# Numbering observations by group

Tags: r

I am attempting to number the observations within group and then identify the first and last observation within each group.  I know how to do this and have even posted the solution here in response to a past question.

However, I have now stumbled upon a situation in which my solution does not work and I cannot figure out why.  Thank you for any advice on how to get the second example below to work.  The first example does work.  Sorry if I am overlooking a silly typo.

I prefer using base R.

```
####################################################################

# this works

my.df = read.table(text = '
   state   county   city   miles
       1        1      1       3
       1        1      1       4
       1        1      1       4
       1        1      1       5
       1        1      2       4
       1        1      2       3
       1        2      1       4
       1        2      2       2
       1        2      2       4
       1        2      2       3
       1        2      3       3
       1        2      3       2
', header = TRUE)

my.df
str(my.df)

my.seq <- data.frame(rle(my.df$city)$lengths)
my.seq

my.df$first <- unlist(apply(my.seq, 1, function(x) seq(1,x)))
my.df$last  <- unlist(apply(my.seq, 1, function(x) seq(x,1,-1)))
my.df

my.df2 <- my.df[my.df$first==1 | my.df$last == 1,]
my.df2

####################################################################

# This does not work.  Only the data set has changed.

my.df <- read.table(text = '
   state   county    city    miles
      40        8       1       12
      40        8       1        4
      40        8       2       13
      40        8       2        3
', header = TRUE)

my.df
str(my.df)

my.seq <- data.frame(rle(my.df$city)$lengths)
my.seq

my.df$first <- unlist(apply(my.seq, 1, function(x) seq(1,x)))
my.df$last  <- unlist(apply(my.seq, 1, function(x) seq(x,1,-1)))
my.df

my.df2 <- my.df[my.df$first==1 | my.df$last == 1,]
my.df2

# The expected result with the second example is:

desired.result <- read.table(text = '
   state   county    city    miles   first   last
      40        8       1       12       1      2
      40        8       1        4       2      1
      40        8       2       13       1      2
      40        8       2        3       2      1
', header = TRUE)

####################################################################
```

Answer (score 1):

Ii was complicated to understand what do you try to do.

I think you get an error because of particular case of unique city !

here how I would do this:

The difficulty here is to create the grouping variable:

```
xx <- rle(my.df$city)
my.df$group <- rep(seq_along(xx$values),xx$lengths)
```

Then using `ddply`, you take the first and the last of each  group:

```
library(plyr)
res <- ddply(my.df,.(group),function(x){
  y <- rbind(head(x,1),tail(x,1))
  cbind(y,data.frame(first=c(1,nrow(x)),
                     last = c(nrow(x),1)))
})
```

Finally you remove duplicated elements using `unique`:

```
unique(res)

 state county city miles group first last
1    40      8    1    12     1     1    2
2    40      8    1     4     1     2    1
3    40      8    2    13     2     1    2
4    40      8    2     3     2     2    1
```

**EDIT** base R solution , just replace `ddply` by `tapply`:

```
group <- rep(seq_along(xx$values),xx$lengths)

tapply(my.df,group,function(x){
  y <- rbind(head(x,1),tail(x,1))
  cbind(y,data.frame(first=c(1,nrow(x)),
                     last = c(nrow(x),1)))
})
unique(res)
```

Comment: Thank you.  +1.  Although I should have indicated that I would prefer a solution in base R.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to modify my code so that I get the desired answer with both example data sets.

I simply added `as.vector()` around my two `unlist(apply())` statements.  Here is the code for the second example:

```
my.df <- read.table(text = '
   state   county    city    miles
      40        8       1       12
      40        8       1        4
      40        8       2       13
      40        8       2        3
', header = TRUE)

my.df
str(my.df)

my.seq <- data.frame(rle(my.df$city)$lengths)
my.seq

my.df$first <- as.vector(unlist(apply(my.seq, 1, function(x) seq(1,x))))
my.df$last  <- as.vector(unlist(apply(my.seq, 1, function(x) seq(x,1,-1))))
my.df

my.df2 <- my.df[my.df$first==1 | my.df$last == 1,]
my.df2
```

Here is the result:

```
  state county city miles first last
1    40      8    1    12     1    2
2    40      8    1     4     2    1
3    40      8    2    13     1    2
4    40      8    2     3     2    1
```